# SwipeRefreshLayout inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swiperefreshlayout, onscrolllistener

I have an activity that consists of a Toolbar and a view pager. Its layout is as follows:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="112dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    tools:context=".Rhino68PanelActivity" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tap_strip"
        layout="@layout/tab_strip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I then load two fragments into the view pager. Each fragment contains its own `SwipeRefreshLayout`. I will show one fragments layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="12"
    tools:context=".Rhino68PanelActivity$DummySectionFragment">
    ...        
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_panel_status"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now when I run the activity it seems to work. However I have noticed that is I slide horizontally  (ie to go to the next tab). It triggers the `swipeRefreshLayout` OnRefreshListener

```
     mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                DoUpdate();
            }
        });
```

I am also experiencing odd visual behavior when I do try and do a refresh. The loading sign (spinning circle) often doesn't show, and it sometimes shows but stays small. I'm not sure if this is also a cause of the two views conflicting with one another.

Is there some way that I can fix this issue. I'm not to sure how. Maybe by limiting the SwipeRefreshLayout to only listen for vertical swipes?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have this issue inside my project, which also uses a similar structure. Can you post a sample project that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Would you care to share your layout? Surely the two layout will interfere with one another? If i even just taped the `SwipeRefreshLayout`  it would trigger the `OnRefresh()`

Comment: There is a slop interval before either of these `ViewGroup` take over the touch event, and it is determined by whether the drag was more vertical or horizontal. Once a touch event is taken over by a `ViewGroup`, it continues to handle the event without interference (using the `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()` method). My app and layout is quite complicated and also confidential, it would help if you could post a minimal sample project with this issue (so that I can debug it).

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/tabs-with-swipe-views/#more-79

Answer (score 3):

I also had this stupid issue. It appears to be a bug in `SwipeRefreshLayout`. As a workaround I had to remove all its child views in `Fragment.onDestroyView()` method.

```
public SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
...

@Override public void onDestroyView() {
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.removeAllViews();
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because there is a bug in SwipeRefreshLayout!
The bug is "onRefresh doesn't work properly if the onMeasure is not called"
You should extends SwipeRefreshLayout like this!

```
public class SwipeRefreshLoading extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
    public SwipeRefreshLoading(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    public SwipeRefreshLoading(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private boolean mMeasured = false;
    private boolean mPreMeasureRefreshing = false;

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (!mMeasured) {
            mMeasured = true;
            setRefreshing(mPreMeasureRefreshing);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void setRefreshing(boolean refreshing) {
        if (mMeasured) {
            super.setRefreshing(refreshing);
        } else {
            mPreMeasureRefreshing = refreshing;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have RefreshLayout inside ViewPager and `setRefreshing` inside "page" (it was a fragment in my case) does not work for some reasons. By the way, I use your code snippet and I got a little wrong position of refreshing spinner. If you move logic from `onMeasure` to `onLayout` method then position will be correct.

Comment: @IlyaEremin i have a problem in vievpager with refreshlayout - when i triger onrefresh * setrefresg(false) in first   fragment of viewpager then animation is gone (its ok ) - but in second fragment animation is still playing even i called setrefreshinng(false) - i extended layout as above - also moved to onlayout but still no effect also tried post delayed on layout - maybe i should add setrefresh to laid out ?

Comment: @TomaszBest this is stupid question, but I ask. Did you call `setRefreshing(false)` for second fragment `SwipeRefreshLayout`?

Comment: @ilyaeremin im caling onRefresh (via gesture) & setRefresh(false) in fragment(child fragment) not in host fragment... 1) first swipe gesture to triger onRefresh() -> layout is animating  -> in this method call loader to deliver cursor -> loader is calling onUpdate() fragment method which is calling setRefresh(false). it works for first fragment in page adapter (visible one) but when i swipe to second fragment and triger onRefresh by swipe gesture all is going as for first fragment but setRefresh(false) dont stop animation in second fragment (visible one)

Comment: - layout is common for every fragment in view pager - i'm getting reference to refreshlayout befor every call setRefresh -> false ( also im checking if state of refresh layout is same as my call true/false -> if(isRefreshing != refresh) setRefresh(refresh)

Comment: @IlyaEremin - ok i found problem - as I told I used CursorLoaderCallback  -  which works on worker thread - so i need to post my method  which is in onLoadFinished() as runnable on UI thread - small hint - if u do something ensure twice u do it on right thread :D